# two divs next to each other, one with top margin

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the following layout in html. Bigger div 1. Then another div next to it with a margin on the top. If I give float: left to the first div, on giving margin-top to the second div also brings the div 1 down. :(

please suggest.

[image: Picute]

Comment: can u please create a small fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want, tested and working :)

http://jsfiddle.net/4FWWp/

**HTML**

```
<div id="first"><p>Hello<br/>Test</p></div>
<div id="second">World</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#first{
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

#second{
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
    margin-top:52px;
}
```

Comment: Couuld be a good solution but is "rigid"...  I mean that force user to have fixed and pre-determined height of 2 boxes

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Dc99N/

```
.d {
    display: inline-block;
    border:2px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.sm {
   margin-top: 50px;
   height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, quick caveat though: IE doesn't support inline-block on elements which weren't initially inline. Solution: `display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1;`

Comment: yea ie7 and below...which is like 2% of your users.

Comment: 2% is overestimation still

Answer (score 0):

[**Flex-box**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) could be the best and easier solution.

IE supports it since version 11, and currently all major browsers have a good support. Maybe is still a little soon but.... I think that in few months could be a very interesting feature.

Please, look at [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: because of IE devs need to probably wait like 2 more years

Comment: Not just IE, but yeah, i agree with around 2 yeats.

Comment: Edited my answer to give more details about compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Took a quick stab at it and it seems possible.
What you need to is display inline-block on the divs and set the height of the divs as percentages.
Check out my codepen  : http://codepen.io/nighrage/pen/bKFhB/
The grey background is of the parent div.